# Excel VBA: Copy and paste duplicate values based on font format

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, italic

I have an Excel format that looks like this:

[image]

What I need is a VBA code in Excel that will read all the data in column A and look for any text in italic format then check if it has a duplicate data on the same column. If yes, that data will be written on column B.

This is what I have so far:

```
 Sub FillDuplicates()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column A

    For x = 1 To lastrow
        If Cells(x, 2).Value <> "" Then 'Check if cell in column B is empty
            For y = 1 To lastrow
                If Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value Then 'Compares cell against each value in column A
                    Cells(y, 2).Value = Cells(x, 2).Value 'If matches, add value in column B
                End If
            Next y
        End If
    Next x
 End Sub
```

Comment: Need to tell you that StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. What did you try so far? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Hi, @Peh. This is what I have so far:

Sub FillDuplicates()
Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row in column A

For x = 1 To lastrow
    If Cells(x, 2).Value <> "" Then 'Check if cell in column B is empty
        For y = 1 To lastrow
            If Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value Then 'Compares cell against each value in column A
                Cells(y, 2).Value = Cells(x, 2).Value 'If matches, add value in column B
            End If
        Next y
    End If
Next x

End Sub

Comment: I just want to know if there's a way to identify whether text is in italic?

Comment: Next time please don't use comments for adding code. You can edit the question to add things like code or images.

Comment: Alright. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: By Googling "vba font italic" you get 115,000 results, the first of which is the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836794.aspx), giving the example `Range("A1:A5").Font.Italic` which returns a Boolean... it took you longer to write the question than it would have taken to search for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
If Cells(x, 2).Value <> "" and Cells(x, 2).Font.Italic = true then
```